# ExtJs 6 what's the best way to define a global data dictionary for use in grid header?

Tags: extjs

I am developing a new application in ExtJs 6 and we have several grids on different screens, which show similar or same data. I want to define a "data dictionary" which will centralize the mappings from our internal data member names to their display names (headers in the grid, labels on forms), and probably other attributes of the data like default column width.

This must be a common problem but I've been unable to find any examples of how other people have done this. My initial attempt was to define a singleton class to hold the mappings, and I'm having some technical issues with that (in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38022864/extjs-6-singleton-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-undefined)). But it occurs to me that the right solution in ExtJs is to keep this data in a store, even if it's statically loaded data.

However, it's not clear to me how to reference the store in the header configuration of the grid. Do I have to set the headers dynamically? (There's no need to load the store from the server, since my data dictionary is statically defined.) I found [this post](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?229323-Dynamic-text-for-grid-column-header) which seemed to suggest setting the header in the renderer, but that seems really ugly...

An example of how others have solved this problem would be really great.

Answer (score 1):

I have a global `Message` object defined in another javascript file, which is loaded from index.html *before* the ExtJS `app.js` file; such that the javascript file is loaded before ExtJS code is executed, and the data is readily available during Ext definition already.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="translations.js"></script>
<!-- The line below must be kept intact for Sencha Command to build your application -->
<script id="microloader" type="text/javascript" src=".sencha/app/microloader/development.js"></script>
```

The object is something like this:

```
if(browser_language == "DE")
Message = {
    ADD: "Hinzufügen",
    ...
    YES: "Ja"
}
else 
Message = {
    ADD: "Add",
    ...
    YES: "Yes"
}

Message.getValue = function(str) {
    if(typeof Message[str]=="string") return Message[str];
    console.log("Translation string "+str+" missing.");
    return str;
}
```

That way, I can use them everywhere through my ExtJS app:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.AddWindow',{
    extend:'Ext.Window',
    title:Message.getValue("ADD"),
    ...
});
```

and it is correctly replaced.

Comment: This might be a reasonable approach for holding messages, but still faces the same problem in that I haven't found any way to use it in the header configuration of a grid.

Comment: Please add a sample of your required header config to your question.

Comment: After further testing I've found that the grid header configs cannot contain executable javascript code (for some reason it works in Sencha App Watch and Sencha Fiddle but not when you deploy the real code). So I think the headers have to be set dynamically.

Comment: Actually, it appears you are setting the title on the window by invoking your object in your window config. Is Message a singleton? Can you share the rest of your definition of Message? Maybe it is what I'm looking for.

Comment: `Message` is just a global javascript variable. As I said, the variable is filled before Ext definition starts, and is used already during component definition, not during component instantiation. I won't post the long list of all my translation strings.

Comment: I'm looking for how you define Message, and where you instantiate it. Is it defined in the translations.js file that appears in your index.html?

Comment: Yes, it's the only thing that's in the translations.js file.

Comment: This is working now for me, I have upvoted your answer and it seems to be the only way to use the grid header config in ExtJs. I am still holding out for a solution that works in ExtJs, for instance because I'd like to someday convert my data dictionary to be dynamically loaded from the server into a store, but I don't think it will be able to use the grid config. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest 2 options that I stumbled upon in the past. Maybe one or why not both will suit you.

### 1. First one is similar to the one suggested by *Alexander*

I created a new file `app\utils\Config.js` and I included it in the *requires* section of `Application.js`. The file defines a singleton class:

```html
Ext.define('MyApp.utils.Config',{
    singleton: true,
    config : {
        proxyBaseUrl: 'http://www.example.com',
        autoRefreshInterval: 10 * 1000,
        componentTypes: [
            ['application', 'application'],
            ['documentation', 'documentation'],
            ['configuration', 'configuration'],
        ]
    },
    constructor : function(config){
        this.initConfig(config);
    }
});
```

I get the defined parameters like this `MyApp.utils.Config.getProxyBaseUrl()`.

Note: `componentTypes` represents the data of a store used in a `combobox`.

Note 2: I also have a `Methods.js` file.

### 2. Dynamically load the grid's configuration

Add this handler for the grid's `metachange` event:

```
grid.getStore().on('metachange', function (store, meta) {
    grid.reconfigure(store, meta.columns);
});
```

When I load the grid's store the server responds with a json similar to this

```
{  
   "metaData":{  
      "columns":[  
         {  
            "header":"Parameter",
            "dataIndex":"paramter_name",
            "width":150
         },
         {  
            "header":"Column 2 Name",
            "dataIndex":"22",
            "sortable":false,
            "minWidth":180,
            "flex":1
         },
         {  
            "header":"Column 3 Name",
            "dataIndex":"0",
            "sortable":false,
            "minWidth":180,
            "flex":1
         }
      ]
   },
   "data":[  
      {  
         "paramter_name":"data_sample1",
         "22":"data_sample2",
         "0":"data_sample3"
      }
   ]
}
```

Note: If you do not want to use this approach and you want to have the grid's configuration on the client side you can:

- Create another store that uses a local .json file
- Switch between stores